# Remove tooltip from charts.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

I am using a plugin: [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

On hovering a radar chart (the bullets in it) a tooltip is shown. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code to Disable the tooltip option..

**Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;**

Answer (score 10):

A layout for a chart with no tooltips would look like this:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        tooltips: { enabled: false },
        ...
        }
     })
```

I know some others have said exactly this, but this is a more complete example.

Comment: All tooltip options can be found @ https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 2):

In ChartJS version 3.4.1 the tooltip configuration is located under `options.plugins.tooltip` - [source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

So a chart without tooltips would look like this:

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            tooltip: { enabled: false },
            ...
        }
    }
})
```